# numpy - use arrays as start and end of range

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is a simplified array of what I have:

```
a = np.array([ 1, 12, 60, 80, 90, 210])
b = np.array([11, 30, 79, 89, 99, 232])
```

How can I get a result that uses `a` as the start range, and `b` as the end of the range, that can compute a list of numbers (quickly).

so, `c` would look like:

```
c = np.array([1,2,3,...,11, 12,13,14,...,29,30, 
              60,61,62,...79, ..., 210,211,...,231,232])
```

Ideally, this would be done in a vectorised way (using numpy/pandas) rather than python.

Comment: You should be able to use `zip()` here. Are `a` and `b` always the same size?

Comment: If you import `add` from `operator`, you can do the following: `c = np.array(reduce(add, [range(x, y) for x, y in zip(a, b)]))`

Comment: You can try doing it this way: `c= np.array(np.concatenate([np.arange(a[i],b[i]+1) for i in range(len(a))]))`.

Comment: I don't know about the speed difference in `np.concatenate()` vs using `reduce()` and `add()`, but I like @VasilisG.'s solution because it doesn't require any additional imports.

Comment: You can also use a combinateion of Vasilis' and pault's answer, `c = np.concatenate([np.arange(x,y+1) for x,y in zip(a,b)])`

Comment: @ThomasKühn thank you, I was about to say that. Using `zip` is better.

Comment: Excellent answers, much more readable than the 'duplicated' answer provided by Divakar, although his is quicker. Thanks guys.(Still checking if Divakar's answer gives me the correct result - got a large dataset to check through)

Comment: @AH Would love to hear about the timings on your dataset.

Comment: My array of ~50,000 items (in each a & b)

Using your answer Divakar:
1.92 ms ± 48.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Using the other answer:
97.6 ms ± 3.07 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

So 2 orders of magnitude, something to be expected of doing it vectorised. Thank you all for your answers :).

Comment: Yeah, NumPy is good with those vectorized ones :)

Comment: It's often the case that for small exanples, list operations are faster.  The array version may have larger overhead, and thus only has the advantage when the problem becomes large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the comments above: One way is to use `zip()` and `np.concatenate()`.

`c = np.concatenate([np.arange(x, y+1) for x, y in zip(a,b)])`

HT to @VasilisG. And @ThomasKühn